# How can I set up a virtual background for video conferencing software?

Tags: skype, conferencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Greenscreen (aka chroma key) effect with a webcam?](https://superuser.com/questions/15198/greenscreen-aka-chroma-key-effect-with-a-webcam)

I've been using Skype since its inception and think it's the greatest of tools, however I have a challenge I need guidance with at this time:

I have an international seafood trading and brokerage business, and we use Skype video whether we've at home, in a hotel room, the bedroom, the bathroom, the office, in a restaurant, or at picking up the kids at day school and this doesn't lend itself for a very professional background. I need help and suggestions for a virtual background which we can use successfully with Skype video regardless of where we are and keep a very professional look - nothing funny or silly like you would see with iPhoto.

This needs to be incorporated whereby, when signing on Skype video, the background might show our logo or a harbor scene with our logo, etc.

If anyone has any ideas of how we can simply incorporate a virtual, not physical, background we can use when video conferencing with customers, suppliers, co-brokers, logistics providers, bankers, etc, this would be a huge help.

Comment: Sharing personal contact info is not a great idea.  Also, please do not use ALL CAPS when posting.  Not considered polite.

Comment: I decapsfyied this so it would actually be readable.  As far as your specific problem, it can be done but depending on the lighting and background conditions I don't think there is a foolproof way to do it...have you considered that maybe video conferencing isn't right for your use?

Comment: The following thread should help you: [Greenscreen (aka chroma key) effect with a webcam?](http://superuser.com/questions/15198/greenscreen-aka-chroma-key-effect-with-a-webcam)

Comment: @Karan Looks like a duplicate Nice catch! (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Skype, there's [Magic Camera](http://shop.skype.com/apps/Games-and-entertainment/Magic-Camera.html) under Skype Apps on their "extras" page.

Within the main features list, I've highlighted the relevant feature you're looking for:

> - Languages: English, Arabic, Bulgarian, Chinese, ChineseSimplified, ChineseTraditional, Danish, French, German, Hungarian, Italian, Lithuanian, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Spanish
> - Add pre-recorded video, photo albums, animations and desktop screens to your Skype calls.
> - Record Skype video calls.
> - Create amazing video effects with just one click.
> - Funny photo frames and fantastic video transforming effects available.
> - Face tracking and mask effects available.
> - Type or paint pictures directly on your video calls.
> - Webcam video overlay.
> - Picture in picture.
> - **Real-time video backgrounds replacement.**
> - Free webcam effect packages available online.
> - Make your webcam avaliable in multiple applications in the same time.
> - New, easy to use design.

[image: App screenshot]

They have a free trial, and if it solves your issue, it costs $19.95.